# AES-128 (OFB mode) in python, trouble with key or text or IV size

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I have a string, that I know has been encrypted using AES-128. I can decrypt it using this PHP code:

```
$key  = "some-key";
$data = "VAZ8AePlKF+TD+tGFw==";

$crypt = base64_decode($data);

$text = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_OFB);

echo $text;
```

The output is `Hello, world!`, as expected.

However I would like to implement this code in python, but I got errors about key size or text-size, or IV...

Here's my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

key = 'some-key'
ciphertext_b64 = 'VAZ8AePlKF+TD+tGFw=='
ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext_b64)

mode = AES.MODE_OFB

decryptor = AES.new(key, mode)
plain = decryptor.decrypt(ciphertext)
print plain
```

What is wrong? Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: the key is `some-key`, length is 8.

Comment: AES uses a key size of 128, 192, or 256 bits (16/24/32 bytes).

Comment: I want to implement the php code in python. I don't know how php handle the insufficient key length, but the code works.

Comment: Then I guess this is more of a PHP question than a Python one. I also don't see you providing an IV in either Python or PHP. I'm surprised PHP agrees to decrypt it, and wouldn't be surprised if the result you get from PHP is cryptographically weak.

Comment: According to the [mcdypt docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php), you must provide an IV in OFB mode and the key length must be 16/24/32 bytes, so I'm confused why the PHP code is working in the first place. I get `PHP Warning:  mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 8 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported in /tmp/test.php on line 8`

Comment: The PHP code works because OP uses an older version of PHP and mcrypt pads short IV and key with 0x00 bytes, but that doesn't solve the problem, because there seems to be a bug in OFB handling in pycrypto.

Comment: @ArtjomB. What bug are you referring to?

Comment: @interjay Pycrypto expects the ciphertext to be a multiple of 16 bytes, but that should be necessary for OFB mode, because it's a streaming mode. Furthermore, [I padded the key, IV and the ciphertext](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/c01bb33f631436ac73c7#file-test16-py) only to get "HS╝£⌠,¬ ∞t≈6╨▼4♦" as the decrypted plaintext. At least the first letter is correct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, `key` must be 16, 24, or 32 bytes long.  The length determines which AES mode is used.  So you need to decide which mode you want, then pad `key` to the desired size:

> key (byte string) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), or 32 (AES-256) bytes long.

If you want to zero-pad, you can pad to 32 bytes as follows:

```
padded_key = key + ("\x00" *  (32 - len(key)))
```

Also, the cipher text must be a multiple of 16 bytes.  If it's already been encryped, then it should already be a multiple of 16 bytes.  If it isn't, then presumably it's corrupted data.  On the other hand, when encrypting, you will in general need to pad your plain text, which you can do with:

```
pad_len = (-len(text)) % 16
padded_text = text + ("\x00" * pad_len)
```

Comment: You shouldn't pad it with spaces.